# Unresolved reference in Manim Community with pycharm

Tags: python, manim

I installed Manim community version 0.14.0 using *pip install manim* on Windows 10. I used the code example given on installation page and it works fine in pyCharm terminal window with command

```
    manim -p -ql example.py SquareToCircle
```

But the code window showing error: unresolved reference on the first line

```
from manim import *
```

It looks like that it did not find manim package

Comment: Your Pycharm interpreter needs to be using same environment that you've used the pip command with

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom right of the window, there should be a button to change the python interpreter:
[image: Screenshot]

Make sure that the correct environment is selected (the one in which you have installed Manim).